# Sending mail with Office365 & MicrosoftGraph fails with "Forbidden"

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I downloaded the Office 365 Connect ASP.NET MVC sample code from http://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/5985, registered it as an application in Azure Active Directory (I have Global Administrator rights), gave it the required permissions - 'Sign in and read user profile' and 'Send mail as a user' (no others), and configured web.config with 'ClientID' and 'ClientSecret'. The application allows me to connect with Office 365, but returns "Forbidden" when I attempt to send email.

Using the VS2015 debugger I captured the AccessToken that I received upon login, and decoded it with http://jwt.calebb.net/. It says the token provides "User.Read" permissions, and that's all.  I understand that the token only provides permissions that are available from both the application and the user credentials used to login to Office 365.  But I have verified using Outlook Web Access that the user credentials do have a mailbox and permission to send email.

So, any thoughts on why I am not getting all the permissions that I configured in AAD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time you sign in before using the app, can you add **&prompt=consent** to the end of the url? It should look something like this:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=...&nonce=e231a375-6925-47d2-8704-9fce2d900620&prompt=consent

This prompts a reconsent so that updates to permissions you made are surfaced to the user, they can consent to it, and those permissions will be included in the returned token.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've set up Send Mail as an Application Permission (authenticates as the app using client credentials - typically as more of a background process) instead of Delegated Permission (authenticate as a particular user).

Comment: The two permissions I've set - 'Sign in and read user profile' and 'Send mail as a user' are both Delegated Permissions that do not require Administrator access.